# How to solve this optimization problem where the constraint requires the solution to an exponential power of 2?

Tags: optimization, linear-regression

I want to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\min_{\bf{w}} (y-\bf{w}^{T}\bf{x})^2 , \\
    &\text{subject to} \quad \forall i, |w_i-w_{i+1}|=2^{r_i}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
here, $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{w}$ are both $N$-dimension column vectors, $y$ is a scalar and $r_i$ is a constant. The constraint means that the absolute value of the difference between any two adjacent elements in $\bf{w}$ must be an integer power of 2. For example, if $N=3$, then $\bf{w}$$=[w_1,w_2,w_3]^{T}$, and it should satisfy that $|w_1-w_2|=2^{r_1}, |w_2-w_3|=2^{r_2}$.

#### My opinion

Let's take $N=3$ again.

##### Case 1: $r_i$ is known.

In this case I think we can use SGD method to solve the following problem
$$
 \min_{\bf{w}} ||\bf{w}^{T}\bf{x}-y||^2_2 + \sum_{i=1}^{2}\lambda_i  ||(|w_i-w_{i+1}|-2^{r_i})||^2_{2}
$$
We can obtain an approximate solutions by adjusting the value of $\lambda_i$ using SGD method.

##### Case 2: $r_i$ is unknown.

In this case the problem is knotty, since we don't know the detailed distance between $w_i$ and $w_{i+1}$ and what we know only is that the distance satisfies that it it an integer power of 2.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: First of all, your notation doesn't make any sense. If $\bf x,w$ are vectors, then $\bf w^Tx$ is a scalar, which then does make sense with subtracting the scalar $y$ (though why are you denoting this scalar in boldface, while the other scalars are not?). But then you take the $L^2$ norm. That is defined on *vectors*, not *scalars*. Did you perhaps mean $\min_{\bf w} (\mathbf w^T\mathbf x - y)^2$? (I could have changed the norm into an absolute value, but $|t|^2 = t^2$, so it can be dropped altogether).

Comment: Second, if the $r_i$ are known, that means $\bf w$ is entirely dependent on its first coordinate $w_1$. which reduces the whole thing to the trivial task of solving a single variable affine equation in $w_1$. SGD method (whatever that means) is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi, @PaulSinclair, thank you for your comment and I have changed $\bf{y}$ to $y$,  (this error is due to the fact that I are not familiar with stackexchange). What you're saying is all right, but I'm more interested in the solution for case 2. Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: That said, Choose all the $r_i = 0$, and drop the absolute value on the condition. Now you are back to (1), and can solve the affine equation for the $w_1$ that makes ${\bf w^Tx} = y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my last comment pushed this through to a full answer, let me post it as such with a fuller explanation.

**Case 1**: You know the differences between $|w_{i+1} - w_i|$. Define $d_i = w_{i+1} - w_i$, so the $|d_i|$ are known, but not their signs. Then for all $i > 1, w_i = w_1 +\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} d_k$. For convenience, let $D_i = w_i - w_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} d_k$, (including $D_1 = 0$). Now

$${\bf w^Tx} = \sum_i w_ix_i = \sum_i w_1x_i + \sum_i D_ix_i = w_1A +  B$$
where $A = \sum_i x_i$ and $B = \sum_i D_ix_i$. We have two cases:

- $A \ne 0$: Then we can choose to make all the $d_i$ positive, so $B$ is known, and set $w_1 = \dfrac {y-B}A$ to obtain ${\bf w^Tx}-y = A\dfrac {y-B}A + B - y = 0$ as the minimum.
- $A = 0$: Then ${\bf w^Tx}-y = B - y$. Now $$B = \sum_{i=1}^N D_ix_i = 0x_1+\sum_{i=2}^N \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} d_kx_i = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}d_k\sum_{i=k+1}^N x_i = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\pm B_k$$ where $B_k = |d_k|\left|\sum_{i=k+1}^N x_i\right|$ are all known values, and the only options are whether to use $+$ or $-$ for each. Sort the $B_k$ from largest to smallest. If $-y \le 0$, choose to add the largest $B_k$, otherwise subtract it. If the result is $\le 0$, choose to add the second largest $B_k$, otherwise subtract. Continue in this wat until all the signs are chosen. The square of the final result will be $\min_{\bf w}({\bf w^Tx} - y)^2$.

**Case 2**: The differences $|w_{i+1} - w_i|$ are required to be integral powers of $2$, but the specific powers are not specified. Again, it will depend on whether $A = \sum_i x_i$ is $0$.

- $A \ne 0$: Choose $w_{i+1} = w_i + 1$ for all $i$ (i.e., the $r_i = 0$). Proceed as in Case 1.
- $A = 0$: Let $A_k = \left|\sum_{i=k+1}^N x_i\right|$, so $${\bf w^Tx}-y = -y + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\pm2^{r_k}A_k$$ Again, order the $A_k$ from largest to smallest. For the largest $A_k$, choose to add $2^{r_k}A_k$ if $-y \le 0$, and subtract otherwise. Pick $r_k$ to make the result as close to $0$, above or below, as possible. Then, using the result instead of $-y$, do the same for the second largest $A_k$, and so on. The square of the final result will be $\min_{\bf w}({\bf w^Tx} - y)^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I try it your way, and you are right. Next I want to think about how to extend to any non-convex function $f(w)$, not just convex function $f(w)=w^{T} x$. I think maybe it would be a good idea to let the neural network solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W_0$ the set of vectors $\vec w =(w_1,\cdots,w_n)$ such that $|w_k-w_{k+1}|=2^{r_k}$. Now if $\vec w_0\in W_0$  then $\vec w_0+\lambda \vec v\in W_0$ where $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec v = (1,\cdots,1)$. Now choosing $\vec w = \vec w_0+\lambda \vec v$ we have

$$
\min_{\vec w}(y-\vec w\cdot\vec x)^2 = \min_{\lambda,\vec w_0}(y-\vec w_0\cdot x-\lambda\vec v\cdot\vec x)^2
$$

and the optimal $\lambda = \lambda^*$ is given by

$$
\lambda^* = \frac{(y-\vec w_0\cdot\vec x)\vec v\cdot\vec x}{(\vec v\cdot\vec x)^2}
$$

so we have

$$
\min_{\vec w}(y-\vec w\cdot\vec x)^2 = \min_{\vec w_0}(y-\vec w_0\cdot x-\lambda^*\vec v\cdot\vec x)^2
$$

NOTE

Here $\vec v\cdot \vec x = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ and the problem reduces to select the best $\vec w_0$ amongst the $2^{n-1}$ possible changes of sign in $\vec w_0$.

Comment: Hi, your approach is very enlightening to me, thank you very much.